# Produce a different type with immer in Typescript

Tags: typescript, immer.js

Given a type

```
type Data<T> = Immutable<{ data: T }>
const a: Data<number> = { data: 0 }
```

I'd like to use `immer` to transform this type into `Data<string>`.

```
produce(a, (d) => { d.data = d.data.toString() })
```

This obviously fails: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'` as I'm assigning a string to `Data<number>['data']`.

**This**, however, typechecks, even though it shouldn't!

```
produce<Data<number>, Draft<Data<string>>>(a, (d) => { d.data = d.data.toString() }) // result: Data<number>
```

This isn't sound! `r` *still* has the type `Data<number>`, even though its `data` field contains a `string`. And note that `d.data` is also `Data<string>`.

The only way I've found to make this work is using an `any` cast:

```
produce<Data<string>>(a as any, (d) => { d.data = d.data.toString() })
```

(Though note again that TS will think of `d.data` as `string` here, even though it's `number`. It just works accidentally, because my example is bad—`.toString()` is defined on both!)

Is there a way to make this work in TS at all?